# UCWA Lyncautodiscover "Internal Server Error"

Tags: azure, lync-2013, ucwa

I want to create a UCWA application for my customer.
I installed the Lync server Standard Edition on Windows Azure  and I followed the following steps.

**1)Lync Server 2013 CU1 upgrade**

**2)Configure DNS Records**
   *lyncdiscover as CNAME (Alias)
   lyncdiscoverinternal as CNAME(Alias)*

**3)Configure internal and external ports** 
   *Set-CsWebServer –Identity ls2013.domain.com –McxSipPrimaryListeningPort 5086
   Set-CsWebServer –Identity ls2013.domain.com –McxSipExternalListeningPort 5087*

**4)Run Enable-CsTopology**

**5)Run the bootstrapper - %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Lync Server 2013\Deployment\Bootstrapper.exe**

**6)Modify Lync Internal Certificate**

```
**Request-CsCertificate -New -Type Default,WebServicesInternal,WebServicesExternal -CA <DC\CANAME> -Domainname "LyncdiscoverInternal.sipdomain1, Lyncdiscover.sipdomain1" -Verbose
Set-CsCertificate -Type Default,WebServicesInternal,WebServicesExternal -Thumbprint E5DBFFBCDD9E6C721E6D5C2DE191BCA8ABEE1E1B**
```

**7)Reverse proxy configuration for mobility**
   *In this step,because of Microsoft TMG 2010 cannot use in Windows Server 2012,I used ARR for reverse proxy as the following link.*

**8)The last,when I browse**

*https://lyncdiscover.domain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.svc/root
   https://lyncdiscoverinternal.domain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.svc/root*

I got the error

```
 HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error Module "OCSAuthHelperModule" could not be found
```

How can I work around for this?
Do I have need to uninstall the Lync Server?
When I google,there is no reference site for UCWA development configuration for detail.
Do you have any reference site or book and cau you share me for your information?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Crawl, Walk, Run ;)

Is the SE totally set up OK? Can you sign in from a Lync client internal to the domain (without using auto-provisioning). Does everything work OK.

Then, can you connect using a Lync client outside the domain, using auto-provisioning? What happens? What do the logs say?

Only when you've got all that working and you've got rid of any problems with the Lync setup, that's a good time to look at UCWA access, and troubleshoot that.

Otherwise, you're just looking at a massive black box, and you don't know where to start.

Just my 2p.

Comment: Yes,I can sign in from a Lync client internal to the domain.
But when creating UCWA application as the following link,I got the error.
 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn356799(v=office.15).aspx)
When I send a GET request on the Autodiscovery URL,I got the "Internal Server Error" response and I cannot continue with this error.
I was googled and tried with the various way for lyncdiscover.
But I can't.Is there any way?